# index() doesn't work on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a weird question.
Internet Explorer always gives an error on line 2:

```
this_parent=this_btn.parent(); //.first_cat
joza=this_parent.index()+1; //get element number
```

This code works on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: windows explorer? internet explorer? dora the explorer? Which explorer?

Comment: nevermind, edited it seems :/

Comment: @xdazz no, from the docs: `If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.` http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change variable name, Explorer has some reserved variables.
Write Joza, not joza

```
Joza=this_parent.index()+1; //get element number
```

Comment: I would be amazed if `joza` is a restricted keyword in the IE javascript implementation. If it is, it's the ultimate troll.

Comment: Once I had the same problem in IE with AJAX, when I renamed the variables it worked))

Comment: LoL... that's why IE is called a donkey

Answer (score 1):

```
this_parent=this_btn.parent();
```

should be

```
this_parent=$(this_btn).parent();
```

Comment: If it works on chrome and ff, I doubt this is the issue. See how though :)